# Limit for the Custom options in Manage Option Template

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working on Magento for a Glasses store. For prescription I need a huge number of custom options.

But seems like there is some limit with the number of fields.

I have entered about 12 fields and a total of 125 options so far.

But now once I create more options, it keeps deleting an option at a time as any new option is created.

Is there any limit for the Manage option template?
Or any other work around?

Comment: P.S: I am using "Options Template v1.4.0"

Comment: Try this one https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-templates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried updating the 'max_input_vars' in php.ini ?
seems like the issue is with the PHP configuration and not the Magento!